# Error when trying to run a user control: A Project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly

Tags: c#, user-controls

i have a class library and im trying to test it by using a user control, which i created inside of the same project of the class library. When i try to run it tho it gives me the error in the title, what am i doing wrong?

i tought maybe the user control should be outside of the project but idk

Comment: Take a look at the section of the "[Output type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/application-page-project-designer-csharp?view=vs-2022)" and "[Start from a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/run-program?view=vs-2022#start-from-a-project)"